# How to pass a value from one function to another

Tags: javascript, function, input, checkbox, onchange

```js
  var boxes = document.getElementsByName('toggle');

  function markPreceding() {
    var curIndex = null;
    for (var j = 0; j < boxes.length; j++) {
      if (boxes[j].checked) {
        curIndex = j;
      }
    }
  }

  function checkInputs() {
    for (var k = 0; k <= curIndex.length; k++) {
      boxes[k].checked = true;
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i <= boxes.length; i++) {
    boxes[i].onchange = markPreceding;
    boxes[i].onchange = checkInputs;
  }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="product-1" name="toggle">
<input type="checkbox" id="product-2" name="toggle">
<input type="checkbox" id="product-3" name="toggle">
<input type="checkbox" id="product-4" name="toggle">
<input type="checkbox" id="product-5" name="toggle">
```

Have a problem passing this "curIndex" value to checkInputs function.
This should check inputs before checked input and get its value to do it.

Only ES5 synthax needed for this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: The ES5 Syntax way

```js
const boxes = document.getElementsByName('toggle');

boxes.forEach(function(box, I) {
  box.onclick = function(e) {
    markPreceding(i);
  };
});

function markPreceding(i) {
  for (var j = 0; j < boxes.length; j++) {
    if(j <= i) {
      document.getElementById('product-' + (j + 1)).checked = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('product-' + (j + 1)).checked = false;
    }
  }
}
```

ORIGINAL:

Try using this:

```js
const boxes = document.getElementsByName('toggle');

boxes.forEach((box, i) => {
  box.onclick = (e) => {
    markPreceding(i);
  };
});

function markPreceding(i) {
  for (var j = 0; j < boxes.length; j++) {
    if(j <= i) {
      document.getElementById(`product-${j + 1}`).checked = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementById(`product-${j + 1}`).checked = false;
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason, there seems to be an issue with updating the inputs through the `NodeList` array returned by `document.getElementsByName`. Not sure why, but this code has been verified. See working example [here](https://repl.it/@bradhacker/WeeklyHilariousWorkers).

Comment: It works! But my project requires ES5 synthax, otherwise I would have found some other way to put it together and now I'm stuck with my code.
Anyways - thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem! Would you like me to post the ES5 syntax version so you can mark that as the answer instead?

Comment: Yes, sure!
That would help a lot

Comment: Done! I removed my debugging lines too. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: thanks, but template literals are ES6 synthax.
but anyways, thanks for help)

Comment: Oh, thanks. I completely forgot to remove those. Will edit anyways.